# how pass variable from controller to application.js?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

please help solve the problem.

i did ajax-from for create new records in database:

```
<%= form_for [current_user, @album], :html => { 'data-current-user' => current_user.id }  do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :title %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
<table id="albumsList">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody data-current-user="<%= current_user.id %>">
    <% @albums.each do |album| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= album.title %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', user_album_path(current_user, album.id) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_album_path(current_user, album) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', user_album_path(current_user, album), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>---<span class="destroy_album" data-album-id="<%= album.id %>">destroy</span></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

application.js:

```
$('#new_album').on('submit', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  var currentUserId = $(this).attr('data-current-user'),
      albumTitle = $('input#album_title').val();

  $.ajax({
    url: '/users/' + currentUserId + '/albums',
    type: 'POST',
    data: $('#new_album').serialize(),
    success: function(result){
      handleModal('album create', 'is successfull', '00ff2a', 2000);
      $('#albumsList tbody').append('<tr> \
        <td>' + albumTitle + '</td> \
        <td></td> \
        <td></td> \
        <td><span class="destroy_album" data-album-id="??????">destroy</span></td> \
      </tr>');
    }
  })
});  

function handleModal(title, body, colorHex, timeout){
  // bla bla bla
}
```

albums controller:

```
  def create
    @album = current_user.albums.build(album_params)

    if @album.save
      # @album_id = @album.id
      redirect_to new_user_album_path(@current_user)
    else
      redirect_to new_user_album_path(@current_user), :status => 403 
    end
  end
```

in result user submit the form and:

1. make a new record in database through ajax-request.
2. in the table added a new line with album name

but i need for element `.destroy_album` add the attribute data-album-id with @album.id value. for this i need pass @album.id from controller to application.js and to tpl.html.erb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this to your ajax request above `type: 'POST'`

```
 dataType: "JSON",
```

as you are making json response, try this

```
def create
  @album = current_user.albums.build(album_params)

  if @album.save
    render json: @album, status: ok
  else
    render json: @album, status: 403
  end
end
```

now on success

you can retrieve the id like this

```
result.id
```